# document.querySelectorAll length is always 0

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create some draggable boxes in javascript. I decided to make an empty class "draggable" in CSS and a "box" class. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .draggable
    {

    }
    .box
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80px; height: 60px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #CCC;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="draggable box">1</div>
<div class="draggable box">2</div>
<div class="draggable box">3</div>
<script>
    var draggableStuff = document.querySelectorAll('draggable');
    var tabLength = draggableStuff.length;
    alert(tabLength);
</script>
</body>
```

The problem is that tabLength is always zero. I want to get an array filled with all draggable stuff. I'm new to javascript. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to select elements by class, so don't forget about the dot:

```
var draggableStuff = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
```

Another option is to use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
var draggableStuff = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
```

Comment: @Michael Np. Tip for the next time, before asking why something is not working, make sure that you have read the correct documentation. For JavaScript/CSS/HTML, the Mozilla Developer Network is generally a good one. Add `mdn` to your search query, eg. [`querySelectorAll mdn`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+querySelectorAll), and you often get the right docs immediately: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: @Rob W: Might want to correct the `BY` on `document.getElementsBYClassName`.

Comment: Nobody else corrected `getElementsBYClassName` to `getElementsByClassName` so I came back from seven and a half years in the future to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this situation. Although it is too old post I would like to help people with my answer:

To select all the elements (no matter what it is, it may be div, span, h1, etc...) with particular attribute

Without value?:

```
var dragables = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable]');
```

With value?:

```
var dragables = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]');
```